# Un problema que no logro resolver en Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let text = document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
  next = document.getElementById("next"),
  previous = document.getElementById("previous"),
  i = 1,
  onlyOneClick = false;

  text.forEach(el=>{
  el.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  let target = e.target;
  if (!onlyOneClick){
  target.classList.add("anyClass")
  } else {
  return;
  }
  onlyOneClick = true;
  });
    });

  next.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ 
  ++i;
  changeText(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3])
  onlyOneClick = false;
  });

  previous.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  if (i > 0){ --i }
  changeText(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3]);
  onlyOneClick = true;
  });

  function changeText(element1, element2, element3, element4) {
    element1.innerHTML = `Any text ${i}`;
    element2.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+1}`;
    element3.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+2}`;
    element4.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+3}`;
  }
  
}
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
body > div:first-child{
display: table;
}
#container{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
position: relative;
padding: 25% 0;
width: 300px;
}
u{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.text{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#next{
float: right;
}
button{
background: black;
color: azure;
padding: 10px 30px;
border: none;
}
button:hover, .text:hover{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0.6;
}
button:focus{
outline: none;
}
button:active{
transform: scale(0.85);
}
.anyClass{
background-color: darkblue;
color: azure;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="container">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 10px;"><u>Any title</u></h1>
    <div class="text">Any text 1</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 2</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 3</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 4</div>
  </div>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hola, tengo este script que al hacer click en cualquier div con clase `.text` agrega la clase `.anyClass` , el problema es el siguiente: Haces click en cualquier de esos divs se agrega un background azul, despues das click en next te debe quitar la clase `.anyClass` ya que sigue pareciendo y luego al hacer click en previous, debe seguir manteniendo el fondo azul en el div antes clickeado.

Ejmp más claro: Se hace click en el primer div con texto: "Any text 0", se agrega la clase `.anyClass`, luego al hacer click en next, su texto cambia a "Any text 1", al cambiar el texto, debe quitarse la clase  que antes se agregado, y si haces click en previous, debe seguir manteniendo la clase `.anyClass` en el texto "Any text 0". Asi debe funcionar cada vez que se cambie el texto en cualquier de los 4 divs.

Espero que se pueda entender mi pregunta. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo unico que haces es cambiar el texto, pero nunca limpias la clase que ya tienes agregada, podrias colocarle una funcion y llamarla al hacer click a previous y next, algo asi:

```
function removeColor(classx, remove){
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(classx)).forEach((el) => el.classList.remove(remove));
      }
```

Al final tendrías algo asi, cabe resaltar que no mantendrias el color en la posición 0, ya que es el mismo tag con diferente texto solamente:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let text = document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
  next = document.getElementById("next"),
  previous = document.getElementById("previous"),
  i = 1,
  onlyOneClick = false;

  text.forEach(el=>{
  el.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  let target = e.target;
  if (!onlyOneClick){
  target.classList.add("anyClass")
  } else {
  return;
  }
  onlyOneClick = true;
  });
    });

  function removeColor(classx, remove){
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(classx)).forEach((el) => el.classList.remove(remove));
  }
  next.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ 
  removeColor('text','anyClass');
  ++i;
  changeText(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3])
  onlyOneClick = false;
  });

  previous.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  if (i > 0){ --i }
  removeColor('text','anyClass');
  changeText(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3]);
  onlyOneClick = true;
  });

  function changeText(element1, element2, element3, element4) {
    element1.innerHTML = `Any text ${i}`;
    element2.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+1}`;
    element3.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+2}`;
    element4.innerHTML = `Any text ${i+3}`;
  }
  
}
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
body > div:first-child{
display: table;
}
#container{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
position: relative;
padding: 25% 0;
width: 300px;
}
u{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.text{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#next{
float: right;
}
button{
background: black;
color: azure;
padding: 10px 30px;
border: none;
}
button:hover, .text:hover{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0.6;
}
button:focus{
outline: none;
}
button:active{
transform: scale(0.85);
}
.anyClass{
background-color: darkblue;
color: azure;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="container">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 10px;"><u>Any title</u></h1>
    <div class="text">Any text 1</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 2</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 3</div>
    <div class="text">Any text 4</div>
  </div>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tu codigo funciona bien, pero al hacer click en previous debe seguir mostrando el fondo azul en el div que clickeaste

Answer (score 0):

primero te recomiendo colocar en archivos separados el javascript, css y html. En mi caso aqui está la respuesta que da solución. Es literalmente un menu de opciones que se llena desde un array.

Aqui el Javascript:

```
var arrayMenu = [
    {id: 1, option: 'Any text 1', class: 'text anyClass', method: 'onClickedOptionMenu(this)'},
    {id: 2, option: 'Any text 2', class: 'text', method: 'onClickedOptionMenu(this)'},
    {id: 3, option: 'Any text 3', class: 'text', method: 'onClickedOptionMenu(this)'},
    {id: 4, option: 'Any text 4', class: 'text', method: 'onClickedOptionMenu(this)'}
];

document.onload = createMenu();

i = 1;

function createMenu() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('container');
    arrayMenu.forEach(e => {
        menu.innerHTML += '<div id="item'+ e.id +'" item-id="' + e.id + '" onclick="'+ e.method +'" class="'+ e.class +'">' + e.option + '</div>'
    });
}

function removeSelectedOption() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="item"]');

  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.setAttribute("class", "text");
  });
}

function changeText(operation) {

    var {id} = getSelectedOption();

    if (operation === "next" && id == arrayMenu.length) {
        i++;
    } else if (i > 1) {
        i--;
    }

    document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = `Any text ${i}`;
    document.getElementById("item2").innerHTML = `Any text ${i + 1}`;
    document.getElementById("item3").innerHTML = `Any text ${i + 2}`;
    document.getElementById("item4").innerHTML = `Any text ${i + 3}`;
}

function getSelectedOption() {
    return {
        item: document.querySelector("div[class='text anyClass']"),
        id: document.querySelector("div[class='text anyClass']").getAttribute('item-id')
    };
}

function scrollMenu() {

    var {id} = getSelectedOption();

    if (id <= arrayMenu.length) {

        removeSelectedOption();

        document
            .querySelector('div[id=item'+ id +']')
            .setAttribute('class', 'text anyClass');
    }
}

function onClickedNextButton(e) {
    var {id} = getSelectedOption();

    id++;

    if (id > 0 && id <= arrayMenu.length) {
        removeSelectedOption();
        var optionMenu = document.querySelector('div[id=item' + id + ']');
        optionMenu.setAttribute('class', 'text anyClass');
    }

    changeText("next");
}

function onClickedPreviousButton(e) {
    var {id} = getSelectedOption();

    id--;

    if(id > 0 && id <= arrayMenu.length) {
        removeSelectedOption();
        var optionMenu = document.querySelector('div[id=item' + id + ']');
        optionMenu.setAttribute('class', 'text anyClass');
    }
    changeText("previous");
}

function onClickedOptionMenu(e) {

  removeSelectedOption();
  e.setAttribute("class", "text anyClass");

  return;
}
```

Luego viene el html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 style="margin-left: 10px;"><u>Any title</u></h1>
        </div>
        <button id="next" onclick="onClickedNextButton(this)">Next</button>
        <button id="previous" onclick="onClickedPreviousButton(this)">Previous</button>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Y el CSS queda igualito a como tu lo pusiste en un principio.

Saludos